# Can't register credit card with Microsoft Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I get the following error when trying to sign up for the Microsoft Azure 90-day free trial:

```
We can't authorize the payment method. Please make sure the information is correct, or use another payment method. If you continue to get this message, please contact your financial institution.
```

I've tried three different cards, two credit and one debit. Those cards are issued from two different banks. I've also tried the cards on two separate accounts. Someone from my work also confirmed that he could not sign up for the free trial either.

Has anyone else had this problem? I haven't really seen much help searching Google and the support staff doesn't seem interested in helping people sign up for free accounts.

Comment: Are you located in one of the supported countries? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/faq/

Comment: Yes, I'm in Singapore. But my  Visa in Vietnam. This can affect the register?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I'm in the US. Tried 3 different (known good) cards. I read on other sites it might have to do with having your Windows Live ID being associated with a business. I checked at http://billing.microsoft.com and my account did have a "business" entry. I made a new Windows Live ID and I was able to sign up for Azure with the new account.

Comment: This question might off topic but for me this answer was the precise solution to the problem. A business account block on the email address. All microsft provides for the error details is a GUID. You'll see "business" in the top right corner of your account page once you log onto billing. If thats so you will be blocked from signing up using that account. This must be inherited fromthe root domain because i specifically set up a new email address under the root domain for azure but it defaulted to "business" in the billing portal. The root domain was previously opted in as business account.

Comment: i tried creating a new account, and it says "US - Personal Account" but windows azure still doesn't accept my card and just gives a GUID.  two cards don't work.